# Is it possible to prevent system() from stealing focus?

Tags: c++, c, windows, cmd, system

I'm on windows. There's something I want to do with system() about every 3-4 seconds, and every system() call opens a cmd window, which would be fine if it didn't also steal focus from whatever I'm doing while my program runs.

Basically, do I have control over system()'s behavior? I'd like it to be as silent as possible.

(I'm trying to run a python script which use the mitsuba bindings. I tried using the Python.h methods to directly call my scripts from the C++ code but I can't get it to work. I feel this would belong in another question, but first I'd like to see if I can get the system() stuff working, unless someone has another solution to run a python script from C code.)

Comment: No.  You'll need to use CreateProcess instead, which has a `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` option.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this looks exactly like what I needed.